# Use substring defined by regex for indexing in solr

Tags: solr, tokenize

I'm trying to manipulate incoming string values for indexing using a regex expression.

Examples IN

- `stack\\overflow@exchange`
- `hello\\world@all`
- `foo\\bar@domain`

Required OUT

- `overflow@exchange`
- `world@all`
- `bar@domain`

As you can see, I would like to split the string using the `\\` characters.
For indexing my values, I've defined the field:

```
<field name="_o_" type="string_t_owner" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
```

And the corresponding field-type

```
<fieldType name="string_t_owner" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(^(.*[\\\/]))" replacement=""/>/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Following procedure:

1. Search for the desired substring
2. Replace it by nothing
3. Tokenizer (or class) is mandatory.

I've also tested the regex and at least using the RegEx-Tester it looks good: https://regex101.com/r/1Qtrol/2

Unfortunately, reindexing my documents results does not return the needed output. Values are not changed, no error message at all.

Based on @MatsLindh hint some additional information:
Putting the following document in the index

```
{
    "_o_":"stack\\overflow@exchange",
    "description":"Testing Indexing",
    "id":"1234"
}
```

I get the following indexed document:

```
{
    "_o_":"stack\\overflow@exchange",
    "description":"Testing Indexing",
    "id":"1234"
}
```

Although through the Analysis page it looks like there's some magic around, but for any reason the desired manipulated information is not stored:
[image: Analysis Results]

Is there anything I've missed for actual storing the manipulated field?

Comment: Are you looking at the stored value, or what the actual indexed content was? (i.e. have you verified what happens if you look at the Analysis page for the content to be indexed under the Solr admin page?)

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the hint in regard to the Analysis-Page. I've updated my question with some additional information :)

Comment: The stored text will not be changed by the analysis sequence, only the tokens that gets stored in the index behind the scenes. And those seem to match what you expect. If you need to change the stored text, either change it before indexing (when submitting) or change it in a update processor.